# Python joining rows of a pandas dataframe over same values and aggregrating string values

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a dataframe of football players stats recorded year by year like this:

```
    df
        player    position    team        stat2015    stat2016    stat2017    stat2018
    0   messi      Wing       Barca       9.85        nan         nan         nan
    1   messi      nan        Barca       nan         5.43        nan         nan
    2   messi      nan        Barca       nan         nan         3.56        nan
    3   dybala     Att        Palermo     15.85       nan         nan         nan
    4   messi      Att        Barca       nan         nan         nan         8.45
    5   dybala     Wing       Juve        nan         7.89        nan         nan
    6   higuain    Att        Napoli      13.22       nan         nan         nan
    7   dybala     Mid        Juve        nan         nan         13.89       nan
    8   higuain    nan        Juve        nan         11.33       nan         nan
    9   higuain    Att        Milan       nan         nan         nan         7.61
    10  ...        ...        ...         ...         ...         ...         ...
```

What i am currently doing is trying to join the rows with the same player, fill the nan values with the stat of the correct year and record the history of the positions and the teams in which the player has played. The output should look like this:

```
    out_df
        player    position        team                    stat2015    stat2016    stat2017    stat2018
    0   messi     [Att,Wing]      Barca                   9.85        5.43        3.56        8.45
    1   dybala    [Att,Wing,Mid]  [Palermo,Juve]          15.85       7.89        13.89       0.0
    2   higuain   Att             [Napoli, Juve, Milan]   13.22       11.33       0.0         7.61
    3   ...       ...             ...                     ...         ...         ...         ...
```

What i've start doing since now is this, but it doesn't seem to work as i'd like to

```py
    out_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = list(df.columns))
    for player in set(df.player):
        temp = df[df.apply(lambda row: row.astype(str).str.contains(player).any(), axis=1)]
        temp = temp.groupby('player').sum().reset_index()
        out_df = out_df.append(temp, sort = False, ignore_index=True)
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Doesnt df.groupby('player') already do that without having to iterate row by row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`DataFrame.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html) to aggregate the groups in different ways according to the expected output:

```
# dict to aggregate with first over stats columns
d = {col:'first' for col in df.filter(like='stat').columns}
# {'stat2015': 'first', 'stat2016': 'first', 'stat2017': 'first', 'stat2018': 'first'}
first_val = lambda x: list(set(x.dropna()))
(df.groupby('player').agg({'position': first_val,
                          'team': first_val,
                          **d}).fillna(0))

             position                team          stat2015  stat2016  \
player                                                                 
dybala   [Wing, Mid, Att]        [Juve, Palermo]     15.85      7.89   
higuain             [Att]  [Juve, Napoli, Milan]     13.22     11.33   
messi         [Wing, Att]                [Barca]      9.85      5.43   

         stat2017  stat2018  
player                       
dybala      13.89      0.00  
higuain      0.00      7.61  
messi        3.56      8.45
```

Comment: Great! Thank you!